# PHP writing vars to txt file, results in duplicate commas/punctuation

Tags: php, text-files

I've got some data posted to a php file, and I need to save/append that data separated by commas to a text file. That's all fine and dandy and should be straightforwards, except for when I check the file I see that every comma has been written twice: once where it needs to be, and then again after the appended data but as a group of commas. 
Here's what I've got:

```
<form action="signup-submit.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New User Signup:</legend>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="16" autofocus required/> <br/>

            <label>Gender:</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" /> Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" checked /> Female</label> <br />

            <label>Age: <input type="text" name="age" size="6" maxlength="2" required></label><br/>

            <label>Personality Type: <input type="text" name="pType" maxlength="4" size="6" required/></label><br/>

            <label>
                Favorite OS:
                <select name="os">
                    <option value="windows">Windows</option>
                    <option value="mac">Mac OS X</option>
                    <option value="linux">Linux</option>
                </select>                    
            </label><br/>

            <label>
                Seeking age:
                <input name="min" type="text" size="6" maxlength="2" placeholder="min" required/>
                to
                <input name="max" type="text" size="6" maxlength="2" placeholder="max" required/>
            </label><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

^that code posts the "user data" to signup-submit.php where it is stored into variables by the same var names.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$pType = $_POST["pType"];
$os = $_POST["os"];
$min = $_POST["min"];
$max = $_POST["max"];

$c = chr(44);
$s = "$name$c$age$c$gender$c$pType$c$os$c$min$c$max";
file_put_contents("single.txt", $s, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

and the text file will unfailingly duplicate the commas as such:

> Byron,21,m,INTP,windows,18,23,,,,,,

the variables are simply data posted to this file from a previous page. I've also tried every which way under the sun to save the data. In fact, if I write only text directly, I get no problems. When I used the csv function I got just commas and no data despite *or so I believed* formatting it correctly.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this?

Comment: do you have that line of code in a loop? if you do please post the extra code that you're not showing

Comment: It would be helpful to see what is actually posting the data and how.

Comment: 1. You should add newlines after each line to see what happens exactly / when the empty lines are added and 2. you should probably use `fputcsv()`.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because sometime all your variables are empty, and you `FILE_APPEND` just commas.

To solve this do:

```
if (!empty($name) && !empty($age) && ...) {
   $s = "$name,$age,$gender,$pType,$os,$min,$max";
   file_put_contents("single.txt", $s, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

If these values are user input always double check them. PHP offers standard functions to sanitize: [Sanitize Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), also you will need input validation with custom rules (for example to check if a variable is within a certain range, but this is a different question).

Comment: The ugly concatenation is only the latest thing I've tried. I've tried using implode() on an array containing this data, writing my own function to transform said array into a string and writing it, etc. but always with the same result.

Comment: did you check if the variables are non empty ?

Comment: I'll make an if-statement like you suggested right now and see if it works (fingers crossed)